# Time complexity of the following function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I would like to estimate lowest i(in term of n) for which this condition fails.

i! < n

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Belongs on Math or Computer Science site

Answer (score 2):

**Taking idea from @ibik's post** :

```
i ! = i* (i-1) *(i-2)* (i-3)* ..... *1
```

> also i-1 < i
>   i-2 < i
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   1 < i

so we get `i! < i*i*i*i......*i` (i times) i.e. `i! < i^i`
therefore `i^i < n`
resulting in :

```
i < n ^ (1/i)
```

which gives : `i = (log n )/ W(log n)`

follow this link : [answer on wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20i-n%5E%281/i%29%20=%200&a=i_Variable)

Comment: same here... i should be in term n only.

Answer (score 0):

It is proved, that the assymptotical complexity of `n!` is same as `n^n`.

Therefore you can rewrite it to `i^i < n`.

Which means `i < sqrt^i(n)`, which is same as `i < n^(1/i)`

Comment: The answer shouldn't have i???